# How can i make it so my scene lights illuminate the inside of this transmissive material

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency

In the image attached, i can see the emissive materials on the inside of the glass bubble, but i want my lights to illuminate the insides so i can see the characters on the inside. I want to achieve this with eevee. Can it be done? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eevee the *Emission* node won't emit any light by default. There are 2 solutions:

- Create a light (like a *Point*)
- Create a *Light Probe > Irradiance Volume* that contains this part of your scene then in the *Render panel > Indirect Lighting*, click on the *Bake Indirect* Lighting button, it will catch the light that is supposed to exist and fake the indirect lighting.